# Java to Sharepoint interface, with claims based authentication

Tags: web-services, security, authentication

I have a sharepoint server with a claims-based authentication (ADFS server).

I have a Java app that needs to push data to a sharepoint list, preferably over the REST API, and with the additional requirement of needing to do it securely (authenticated and over https).

Has anyone done anything like this?  I having the hardest time finding any solution that isn't "code the entire sharepoint/adfs/kerberos auth conversation from the ground up, just to get a fedAuth cookie"

Comment: This seems like a brutal task.  The sources I have read say there really isn't much you can do EXCEPT code your java from the ground up.  Maybe you could try writing a .NET app, and use your java to talk to that?  It seems like a roundabout way to do it, but then you would know exactly how to interface with it and still be able to use the SharePoint API on the .NET end.  I know that's not an ideal solution - just brainstorming.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Trek I please see this links

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c

Using C# how we pass authentication to sharepoint online site.
This may help u.

Answer (score 0):

One cool way to do this is to enter a mediation web service if you have the capability... Write a .net webservice which accepts the parameters you need and use the .net client side api to enter in the  info... I think this will be the least headache for you.

Answer (score 0):

if the sharepoint usese mixed authentication, you can use the header
"X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED"= "f"
to fallback to NTLM

see also
http://myspworld.wordpress.com/tag/claims-based-authentication/
http://buyevich.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/accessing-mixed-authentication-web-app.html

Comment: this little tool will help you authenticate java to sharepoint: https://github.com/DovAmir/httpclientAuthHelper